# Error Select xml colunn SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to select a column in a table which contains XML using XPath.

This is my query:

```
SELECT  
    [ServiceRequestHist].id,[ServiceRequestHist].SoapOut,
    CAST(SoapOut AS XML).value(CONVERT(xml, '(/Envelope/Body/InterbankTransferResponse/InterbankTransferResult/AccountFirstHolderName)[1]', 2), 'varchar(100)') AS AccountFirstHolderName,
    CAST(SoapOut AS XML).value(CONVERT(xml,'(/Envelope/Body/InterbankTransferResponse/InterbankTransferResult/AccountNumber)[1]', 2), 'varchar(100)') AS AccountNumber,
    CAST(SoapOut AS XML).value(CONVERT(xml,'(/Envelope/Body/InterbankTransferResponse/InterbankTransferResult/BeneficiaryBank)[1]', 2), 'varchar(100)') AS BeneficiaryBank
FROM 
    [STBMZ_eBankitMonitoring].[dbo].[ServiceRequestHist]
```

The output is:

> Msg 8172, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal.

Some help?

Comment: I would suggest if you are storing xml data that you use the xml datatype. It looks like you are storing this as a varchar? Also, why are you converting your string literal to xml? That is the issue here. Get rid of that convert(xml....

Answer (score 2):

That looks really wrong. You've got a `CONVERT` in the middle of your `value`.

This isn't tested, as we have no sample data, however, try:

```
SELECT  [ServiceRequestHist].id,[ServiceRequestHist].SoapOut,
        CAST(SoapOut AS xml).value('(/Envelope/Body/InterbankTransferResponse/InterbankTransferResult/AccountFirstHolderName/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as AccountFirstHolderName,
        CAST(SoapOut AS xml).value('(/Envelope/Body/InterbankTransferResponse/InterbankTransferResult/AccountNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as AccountNumber,
        CAST(SoapOut AS xml).value('(/Envelope/Body/InterbankTransferResponse/InterbankTransferResult/BeneficiaryBank/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as BeneficiaryBank
FROM [STBMZ_eBankitMonitoring].[dbo].[ServiceRequestHist];
```

Firstly, I would suggest changing the datatype of `SoapOut` to `xml` in your table; if it's XML store it as `xml`, not a `varchar`. I don't actually know if `CAST(SoapOut AS XML).value...` will work.

Next, also note I used the `text()` operator, as this will improve performance.

*Edit: Again, **untested**, however, for readability I'd probably do this:*

```
SELECT SRH.id,
       X.SO AS SoapOut,
       SON.ITR.value('/AccountFirstHolderName/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as AccountFirstHolderName,
       SON.ITR.value('/AccountNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as AccountNumber,
       SON.ITR.value('/BeneficiaryBank/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as BeneficiaryBank
FROM [STBMZ_eBankitMonitoring].[dbo].[ServiceRequestHist] SRH
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(xml,SRH.SoapOut))) X(SO)
     CROSS APPLY X.SO.nodes('/Envelope/Body/InterbankTransferResponse/InterbankTransferResult/') SON(ITR);
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question. I tried this before but the output is: "Parsing XML with internal subset DTDs not allowed. Use CONVERT with style option 2 to enable limited internal subset DTD support."

Comment: In the second example, the style tag would go in the `CROSS APPLY`, not within the middle of the `value` operator (which is completely the wrong place).

Comment: When I executed the query bellow I faced this error: "XQuery [X.SO.nodes()]: Syntax error near '<eof>', expected a step expression.". Solved after removing the last "/" in "X.SO.nodes('/Envelope/Body/InterbankTransferResponse/InterbankTransferResult/')". Now the output message is "XQuery [X.SO.value()]: No more tokens expected at the end of the XQuery expression. Found ')'."

Comment: @ValterCheque that means you have some malformed xml in your `varchar` column. Another good reason why you need to store your xml as `xml` in your database; as you can't stored malformed data. You'll need to find the offending records and fix the xml. You can't `CONVERT` malformed xml to an `xml`, so you won't be able to achieve what you're after unless you fix your data.